# Wordpress add jquery if not present theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, include

How to add Conditional jquery in wordpress if theme haven't jquery.
I have plugin which use jquery to work but the problem is if i include jquery in plugin and 
theme already included or hardcoded in header jquery so 2times will jquery add in header.

So is their any way if jquery found in theme then plugin jquery not include.

Comment: Scripts in WordPress aren't included in the usual way, they are loaded using a function called `wp_enqueue_script`, if the plugin is doing this(as it should be), you should be able to safely do the same, see [The Codex page here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) on the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery.js">\x3C/script>')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `wp_enqueue_script` mentioned above and rewrote theme header and plugin. That will save you lots of support time in future.